# Why in vuejs2 is my default prop not passed to my child component?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, leaflet

trying to pass a default value to my child component before the desired data is fetched from an API point. But am failing to do so and wonder why?

My child component happens to be a Leaflet map and am passing to it some country coords, like latitude and longitude. I do it like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <LeafletMap
      :latitude="countryStats.countryInfo.lat || 0"
      :longitude="countryStats.countryInfo.long || 0"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

Or like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <LeafletMap
      :latitude="countryStats.countryInfo.lat ? countryStats.countryInfo.lat : 0"
      :longitude="countryStats.countryInfo.long ? countryStats.countryInfo.long : 0"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

but neither way seems to work.

I only get:

> vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError:
> Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined"
>
> found in
>
> --->  at src/components/home/Home.vue

This is my child component:

```
<template>
  <div class="map">
    <h1>World Map</h1>
    <div id="mapContainer">
      <l-map
        style="height: 80%; width: 100%"
        :zoom="zoom"
        :center="center"
        @update:zoom="zoomUpdated"
        @update:center="centerUpdated"
        @update:bounds="boundsUpdated"
      >
        <l-tile-layer :url="url"></l-tile-layer>
      </l-map>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import { LMap, LTileLayer } from "vue2-leaflet";

export default {
  name: "LeafletMap",
  components: {
    LMap,
    LTileLayer
  },
  props: {
    latitude: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    },
    longitude: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      url: "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
      zoom: 4,
      center: [this.latitude, this.longitude],
      bounds: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    zoomUpdated(zoom) {
      this.zoom = zoom;
    },
    centerUpdated(center) {
      this.center = center;
    },
    boundsUpdated(bounds) {
      this.bounds = bounds;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style src="./LeafletMap.css" scoped />
```

Wonder, if I should still give in my child component a default value for my props (`latitude` and `longitude`) or will it cause a conflict?

Any help is welcome.

Comment: can you post your app.vue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As implied by ViniciusSilveiraAlves, the issue is not in your child component (LeafletMap), but in your parent one (Home).

Most probably it has a `countryStats` data item which is assigned an empty object `{}` as initial value. So in the template, when you try to read `countryStats.countryInfo.lat`, countryInfo member is undefined, and trying to get its `lat` member generates your error message (and your ternary occurs too late to prevent it).

An extremely simple solution, if this value makes sense in your situation, would be to initialize `countryStats` with a more complete value:

```js
export default {
  name: "Home",
  data() {
    return {
      countryStats: {
        countryInfo: {} // Just enough so that template gets a defined countryInfo
      }
    };
  }
}
```

If for some reason you do need an empty initial countryStats object, then simply improve your conditions in your template, to make sure first that countryStats.countryInfo is defined:

```html
<LeafletMap
  :latitude="countryStats.countryInfo && countryStats.countryInfo.lat || 0"
  :longitude="countryStats.countryInfo && countryStats.countryInfo.long || 0"
/>
```